# Jira filter missing "Status" option

Tags: filter, jira

I just started my internship at a company that has started to use Jira so I am borderline clueless what to do?

The issue filter used to have a tab for `Status`, and other users that have created filters with the status tab are still active and working, but can't find a way to filter with that choice anymore. It seems to have just vanished.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on `/issues` page.

[Screenshot](http://gyazo.com/bc47e26d4294a9bcb455431fd6b6632c)